# Arbitrarily "bad" representations of irrational $x$ by rational $q/p$ where $p$ is prime

Tags: real-analysis

For given real $x$, the closest rational of the form $q/p$ has distance no more than $1/2p$ to $x$. Suppose we fix positive $c < 1$. For a given irrational $x$, can we find an infinite subset of primes $p$ so that the closest rational $q/p$ to $x$ satisfies $|x - q/p| > c/2p$? If working with primes is too hard, what about whether we can find an infinite subset of positive integers $p$ with the property?

Comment: I don't think it works for $c=1$, because the closest rational $q/p$ should always be distance $\leq 1/2p$.

Comment: @user7530: Setting $c=1$ doesn't make sense. From the first sentence, we know that the closest rational $q/p$ satisfies $|x-q/p| \leq 1/2p$.

Comment: @Théophile Oh I see.

Comment: I don't think primes are anything special in this problem, so would suggest the large positive integers is the interesting one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, at least if you drop the primality requirement.

It [follows](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Rational_approximation#Discussion) from Dirichlet's approximation theorem that for infinitely many even integers $2p$ there is an odd $q$ with
$$\left|x - \frac{q}{2p}\right| < \frac{6}{p^2}.$$
For $p$ sufficiently large $q$ is the best possible numerator for the denominator $2p$.

The best fraction with denominator $p$ is then $\frac{q\pm 1}{2p}$, and
$$\left|x - \frac{q\pm 1}{2p}\right| \geq \frac{1}{2p} - \left|x - \frac{q}{2p}\right| \geq \frac{1}{2p} - \frac{6}{p^2}$$
where the second term can be made arbitrarily small.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to use this to answer another MSE question that almost certainly will require primality unless I can generalize my proof for that question, but this is a very nice answer when the primality restriction is dropped.

Comment: @user2566092 I have a feeling that the question, for prime $p$, is one of those facts that is almost certainly true but extremely difficult to prove...

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot, for any given $c \gt 0$.  There are infinite $p$ such that $|x -\frac pqp| \lt \frac 1{q^\mu}$ is satisfied for infinitely many $p$, where $\mu$ is the [irrationality measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrationality_measure#Irrationality_measure) of the number.  It is $2$ for almost all numbers, but some transcendental numbers are higher.  For your chosen $c$, we just need to require that $q \gt \frac 1c$

Comment: I think I might have been unclear about quantifiers if I understand your answer properly. I'm not asking whether it's possible for the inequality to hold for all sufficiently large $p$, or if we can use the same $p$ for each $x$, but rather whether for $c < 1$, and a given irrational $x$, there is an infinite subset of positive $p$ where the inequality holds. Does your answer still work for that? Meanwhile I'll edit the question

Comment: For $c \lt 1/2$ there will also be an infinite set where there is no good approximation.  This theorem just says that there is an infinite set of $q$'s where the approximation is good.